# Small question about a lemma of measurability

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Hi ;

I have this lemma , and i want to ask tow questions :

1) What is the diffrence between say that $\varphi$ is measurable and to say that $\varphi$ is $(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{B}(U))$measurable .

2)Why $\varphi_{p}(t,x) \rightarrow \varphi(t,x)$ when $p\rightarrow +\infty$.

please,

Help me.

Thank you

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: it's from the book of C.Castain, M-Valadier : convexe and measurable multifunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At page 61 of the book you mention, we can see that "measurable" means that the considered map is $(\mathcal T,\mathcal B(U))$ measurable *and its range is separable*.
2. Fix $t$ and $x$. For each $p$, call $n(p)$ the smallest integer $n$ such that $x\in B(x_n,p^{-1})$. Then $d(x,x_{n(p)})<p^{-1}$. Conclude using the continuity in the second argument.